# Adapter under retrofit thread is null in onCreate method of fragment

Tags: android-fragments, adapter, retrofit2

This is my code:

```
public class TopicsFragment extends Fragment {
    TopicList topicList;
    List<Map<String, Object>> topics;
    TopicsAdapter adapter;
    FragmentActivity listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            this.listener = (FragmentActivity) context;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RubyChinaService service = RubyChinaApi.getInstance().getRubyChinaService();

        //Create a call instance for looking up Retrofit topics.
        Call<TopicList> call = service.getTopics();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<TopicList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TopicList> call, Response<TopicList> response) {
                topicList = response.body();
                topics = DataUtil.ObjectToMapList(topicList);
                adapter = new TopicsAdapter(listener, topics, R.layout.item_topic,
                    new String[]{"authorIcon", "topicTitle", "topicAuthor", "repliesCount"},
                    new int[]{R.id.authorIcon, R.id.topicTitle, R.id.topicAuthor, R.id.repliesCount});
        }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TopicList> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When i used debug feature and create breakpoint in Android Studio, i got a null adapter.
Why?
How to  resolve the problem or orgnize my code?